# Node.js oracledb UPDATE gets stuck (promise never resolved)

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle, oracle11g, node-oracledb

I got an issue with nodejs oracledb package. Executing SELECT queries work, but when I execute one UPDATE query literally the library gets stuck (The promise is never resolved) and none any new other oracle commands will ever get resolved (including new SELECT queries).

```
    const out = await db.connection.execute( `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYFIELD = :1`, ['JOHN] )
```

The above request is resolved while the next UPDATE request gets stuck and the promise is never resolved.

```
    try{
        const out = await db.connection.execute(`UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD = :1 WHERE ID = :2`, ['JOHN', 1])
        console.log("success")
    }catch(err){
        console.error("Error", err)
    }
```

It gets stuck. If I will do another SELECT, the new requests will get stuck as well idefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general cause is that the same (or similar) statement was run in a tool like SQL*Plus or SQL Developer but wasn't committed.  Therefore the row is locked and can't be updated by your Node.js application.

Comment: You were right. This solved my issue. Thx